# Tkinter Time Button Not Outputting

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, time

I am trying to record the time between button presses and then append that time to a list however when I press the `stop_time_forward` button I don't get it printing anything. Any help on this would be amazing.
My Code:

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

initial = 0
top = Tk()
command_time_list = []

#start forward
def start_time_forward():
   global initial
   print("Timer Start")
   initial = time.time()
   return initial

def stop_time_forward():
   final = time.time()
   time_elapsed = final - initial
   command_time_list.append('a')
   command_time_list.append(time_elapsed)
   return command_time_list

forward_output = stop_time_forward()
print(forward_output)

forward_end = Button(top, text ="Forward Time Stop", command = stop_time_forward)
forward_start = Button(top, text ="Forward Time Start", command = start_time_forward)

forward_end.pack()
forward_start.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's because the `stop_time_forward()` doesn't print anything.

Comment: @martineau thanks, any reason that whenever I run the program it automatically outputs a value even before I hit the stop button?

Comment: Because of the `print(forward_output)` call that occurs before entering the `mainloop()`.

Comment: @Agarb Also there is no point to returning anything from a function that is set to a button's `command`

Comment: @martineau okay, I refactored my code a bit but now at the end it is appending the value between the last end and the time I end the program. I don't know what is causing this, any help?

Comment: If you want something to print whenever the `stop_time_forward()` function is called do it in the function, which will happen every time the button is clicked (and stop calling it manually).

Comment: Also note what @TheLizzard said about returning values from callback functions. The only reason I didn't mention it myself was because your code also calls `stop_time_forward()` normally and expects a value from it to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

all what you need to add is print function in stop_time_forward that is called when button forward_end is called

```
import time
from tkinter import *

initial = 0
top = Tk()
command_time_list = []

#start forward
def start_time_forward():
   global initial
   print("Timer Start")
   initial = time.time()
   return initial

def stop_time_forward():
   final = time.time()
   time_elapsed = final - initial
   command_time_list.append('a')
   command_time_list.append(time_elapsed)
   print(command_time_list) # here is the fix
   return command_time_list

forward_output = stop_time_forward()
print(forward_output)

forward_end = Button(top, text ="Forward Time Stop", command = stop_time_forward)
forward_start = Button(top, text ="Forward Time Start", command = start_time_forward)

forward_end.pack()
forward_start.pack()
top.mainloop()
```